# Erro ao usar decorator em um método setter

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos, getters-setters, decorator-pattern

Eu estou tentando implementar um código simples em Python para praticar o uso de decorators em conjunto com métodos assessores (Getters e Setters), porém estou obtendo um erro.

O código é o seguinte:

```
class Pessoa():
    def __init__(self, anos):
        self._idade = 0 
        self.idade = anos

    @idade.setter
    def idade(self, anos):
        self._idade = anos

alguem = Pessoa(18)
```

E o erro que está ocorrendo é o seguinte:

```
NameError: name 'idade' is not defined
```

Não entendi, pois 'idade' existe sim!

Eu pesquisei na internet por exemplos de uso de decorators em conjunto com métodos assessores e encontrei alguns códigos, porém não consegui perceber onde estou errando.

Existe uma forma de implementar somente o método Setter com decorators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao atribuir um _ ou __ (private e protected) você deve tratar os atributos usando um getter antes de passá-lo pelo setter. Essa atribuição é realizada através do @property, seguido do método que retorna o atributo devidamente tratado.

Outros aspectos importantes:

1. não iniciar duas variáveis de mesmo nome, diferenciadas tão somente pelo atributo private e protected (não é, de nenhuma forma, uma boa prática).
2. Ao atribuir uma classe você não deve atribuir o (), isso é uma tarefa do iniciador que você define abaixo. O jeito correto de definir a classe é tão somente "class Nome:"

Seu código seria corrigido da seguinte forma:

```
class Pessoa:
    def __init__(self, anos):
        self._idade = anos

    @property
    def idade(self):
        return self._idade

    @idade.setter
    def idade(self, anos):
        self._idade = anos
```

alguem = Pessoa(18)

Comment: Eu mudaria no `__init__` para `self.idade = anos` para utilizar a propriedade ao invés de definir o valor do atributo diretamente.

Comment: Entendi, mas surgiram outras duas dúvidas: 1° - Existe uma forma de implementar apenas o método setter usando decorators?   2° - Ao você escrever `self._idade = anos`, isso não faz com que o valor de anos seja atribuído diretamente a `self._idade`, inutilizando assim, o método setter criado?

Comment: @Edy Acho que o recomendado é você tentar se aprofundar na questão do encapsulamento... esses protect e private no Python não segue o padrão das outras linguagens. No caso das últimas perguntas... 1- se o atributo é protect ou private não será acessado sem o @ property, ainda que você utilize o @ setter. 2- O self_idade recebe o valor de anos sem nenhum problema, a questão é que a informação da variável não será acessível se o dado não for tratado com os métodos de encapsulamento.

Comment: @VictorDantas Obrigado pelo conselho! Vou buscar me aprofundar mais nos temas relacionados a POO em Python, e principalmente sobre encapsulamento. Outra coisa: eu esqueci de explicar que quando eu escrevi `self.idade = anos` ao invés de estar criando um outro atributo de nome semelhante ao primeiro, na verdade eu estava utilizando a propriedade usada no setter e passando o valor da idade para ela. Mas pelo que pesquisei parece que isso não é um prática muito usual.